# [About choosing params in BGV like ciphertexts]

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto, lwe, ring-lwe

I am new to lattice-based cryptography, so sorry that this question might seems stupid 
May I ask that how can I choose the BGV parameter of ciphertext with plain text in mod 128, and error in gaussian distribution of std 3.19 and secret key in uniform distribution from -1 to 1? Do I need also need to take into account that the computation I want to do? Mine Computation is just multiply by a constant also in mod 128.
I.e. Enc(m) = $A^{T}r+m \mod q$, how can I choose the q?
And I recently find the [lwe estimator](https://github.com/malb/lattice-estimator), is there any way I could calculate the example I mentioned above using this tool? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: https://homomorphicencryption.org/standard/

Comment: Dear friend, it is nice that you have been diving into it and this is now a new question. May be delete this and ask a much better question?

Comment: You may want to check out the lattice estimator, a successor project to lwe estimator. I also posted an article here that shows how to use the tool to estimate RLWE security: https://jeremykun.com/2022/12/28/estimating-the-security-of-ring-learning-with-errors-rlwe/

Comment: @kelalaka, thanks for the advice, I just ask a new question :)

Comment: @JeremyKun, thanks a lot! I have recently tried to find posts/tutorials about using these kinds of tools but have not found one until now!